# How do I display the value of the square's id when hovering over it only?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am not allowed to use any html in this assignment. Here is what I have so far in javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    let button = document.createElement('button');
    let btnText = document.createTextNode('Add Square');
    button.appendChild(btnText);
    document.body.appendChild(button);

    let sqContainer = document.createElement('div');
    sqContainer.classList.add('container')
    document.body.appendChild(sqContainer)

    let num = 0

    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        let square = document.createElement('div')
        square.classList.add('square')
        sqContainer.appendChild(square)
        document.body.appendChild(sqContainer)
        num++
        square.setAttribute('id', num)

        let idDisplay = document.createElement('span')
        idDisplay.classList.add('id-display')
        idDisplay.innerText = num
     })
})
```

This creates boxes that go across the screen horizontally until they reach the end of the page which they then wrap around which i have archived using flex box. Here is my css:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: purple;
}

.square:hover {
   display: num;
}
```

Here is the instructions verbatim: When hovering over a square, the value of the square's id should display centered in the square, and disappear when the cursor is no longer over the square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) that contains the `id` [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr). Set it to `opacity: 0` by default and then change its opacity when the square is hovered.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  const sqContainer = document.createElement('div');

  button.innerText = "Add Square";
  sqContainer.classList.add('container');

  document.body.appendChild(button);
  document.body.appendChild(sqContainer);

  let num = 0

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    num++
    const square = document.createElement('div')
    square.classList.add('square')
    sqContainer.appendChild(square)
    square.setAttribute('id', num)
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
}

.square:before {
  content: attr(id);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.square:hover:before {
  opacity: 1
}
```